# Simple Stack Effects with JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm playing around with https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/05/simple-stack-effects/ right now but I'm struggling to use a link instead of a button as the trigger for this animation.

```
<button>Click me</button>
<figure class="stack stack-sidegrid">
  <img src="img/1.png" alt="img01"/>
  <img src="img/3.png" alt="img03"/>
  <img src="img/4.png" alt="img04"/>
</figure>
```

change to

```
<a href="#">
  <figure class="stack stack-sidegrid">
    <img src="img/1.png" alt="img01"/>
    <img src="img/3.png" alt="img03"/>
    <img src="img/4.png" alt="img04"/>
  </figure>
</a>
```

This is the js script for handling the event.

```
(function() {
    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.stack' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
        var togglebtt = el.previousElementSibling,
            togglefn = function() {
                if( classie.hasClass( el, 'active' ) ) {
                    classie.removeClass( el, 'active' );
                }
                else {
                    classie.addClass( el, 'active' );
                }
            };
        togglebtt.addEventListener( 'click', togglefn );
    } );
})();
```

Does anybody maybe have a suggestion how I get this code to work?

Reference: https://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/05/simple-stack-effects/

Comment: Just make sure that, after loading document you should call above mentioned JS code. I've made a jsfiddle of above example using anchor tag instead of button & it's working. **http://jsfiddle.net/cq0xfL72/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `var togglebtt = el.previousElementSibling,` to `var togglebtt = el.parentElement,`

like this:

```
(function() {
    [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.stack' ) ).forEach( function( el ) {
        var togglebtt = el,
            togglefn = function() {
                if( classie.hasClass( el, 'active' ) ) {
                    classie.removeClass( el, 'active' );
                }
                else {
                    classie.addClass( el, 'active' );
                }
            };

        togglebtt.addEventListener( 'click', togglefn );
    } );
})();
```

In that demo, `togglebtt = el.previousElementSibling` is used as trigger,

`el` is each `<figure class="stack ">`

its `previousElementSibling` is `<button>Click me</button>` according the HTML.

You want to use a link to trigger instead of this button only need to change value of `togglebtt`.

change it to `el` or `el.parentElement`

Comment: It works perfectly and thanks to your detailed explanation!! Really appreciate it :) Thanks!

Comment: glad to help， it's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/IanZhong/6p4ztvfr/7/) seems you don't need now...